# DataGrid refresh issue

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, valueconverter

I have a Silverlight 4 **DataGrid** which has its **ItemsSource** bound to an **ObservableCollection**. When i modify an element of my **ObservableCollection** the modified element is correctly displayed inside my grid except the element of one **column**. This columns differs from the others in the way it is a **TemplateColumn** and it's using a **ValueConverter**.

*The Template for the column consists of a simple stackPanel that includes a Path control and a Label. And the Label is bound to some Source object with the help of a simple ValueConverter.*

The problem now is when i modify some element that belongs to the ObservableCollection all columns of the grid are displayed correctly except the one described above. It simply stays unchanged - but when i use the mousecursor to select the DataGridCell and click it a second time, the desired refresh suddenly happens.

So I guess it's something simple what i am missing here, but I can't find it ...

Thanks in advance ..

**EDIT:**

**In the meanwhile I was able to further locate the problem: It seems that after I modify an element of my ObservableCollection the corresponding ValueConverter that belongs to the label that is in my grid that is bound to the source is simply not called. When i click inside the cell the ValueConverter is getting called as it should. BUT it won't automatically - So how do I achieve that ? please help :)**

**EDIT:**

The binding:

```
<sdk:Label Content="{Binding Route.Legs, Converter={StaticResource IncomingTableRouteTripConverter}}" Margin="9,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource TripLabelTemplate}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="10.667" Padding="0" Height="10" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

This is the code of my ValueConverter:
*(But I don't think that the code of the converter has anything to do with my problem I only posted it here for completeness)*

```
public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

        string trip = "";

        if (value != null) {


            List<Leg> legs = (List<Leg>)value;

            if (legs.Count >= 1) {

                for (int i = 0; i <= legs.Count - 1; i++) {

                    trip += ((Leg)legs[i]).Start.ICAO + " - " + ((Leg)legs[i]).Stop.ICAO + " - ";
                }

                trip = trip.Substring(0, trip.Length - 2);
            }
        }

        return trip;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all nodes in the `Path` notifications need to be in place, so both the class owning `Route` and the class owning `Legs` need to implement [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Further if you add items to the `Legs` list naturally nothing will be updated, in fact even if the `Legs` property were of type `ObservableCollection<...>` that would not matter as the binding engine only cares about `INPC`.

So if you want the binding to update if the collection changes you need to fire property changed for the `Legs` property every time it somehow is modified (including a complete replacement of the reference).

Comment: Hello H.B. :) You were right, i missed it to add some code. I've extened my above post with some code. But it seems that the additional PATH keyword did not bring any change. Did I understand you right with that ?

Comment: @Marc: You already had a path, adding `Path=` changes nothing. (I cannot look at your added code right now, may do later)

Comment: @Marc: Edited my answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: I do fire the propertyChanged event on every attribute I am changing. Legs is a List<Leg> list here, could that be problem ?

Comment: @Marc: As i said, whenever you change the collection, no matter its type, you need to fire a `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: ok I am working hard to get it done. I will let you know if i solved it and what it was. So far thank you :)

Comment: @Marc: Just to clarify again, by "change the collection" i mean not only a reassignment of the Legs property but also operations on the list like `Legs.Add(...)` or `Legs.Remove(...)`. To easily do this you could utilize an ObservableCollection as you could subscribe to the changes and fire the event ( `Legs.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => OnPropertyChanged("Legs");` ).

Comment: but how could it be that if notification fails somewhere in my Path tree, that on a mouseclick the desired change appears ?

Comment: @Marc: Because, as i explained in my previous version of my answer, the grid may change the templates and when your template is reapplied everything is rebuilt and the binding is resolved once again. (At least that would be one plausible explanation)

Comment: @Marc: Yes (but and this is not a chat.)

Comment: yes of course it's not. I just wanted to say that I have opened another thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181562/notification-of-datagrid-when-collection-inside-collection-changes) to try to clarify my problem in more detail. Because I am still trying to solve my problem. Maybe you want to have a look :)

Comment: @Marc: Thanks :) One step closer to [Legendary](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary)... (By the way, not sure if you noticed, you can only accept one answer, so on the other question the accept was moved (i'm fine with that!))

Comment: hehe, good luck :) I will keep on asking questions in the future .. just for you :) for today I will pause the project and the day but tomorrow I am in office again and I am sure I will have a lot of questions to go *lol* ;)

Comment: no I was not aware of that .. I re-shifted because you absolutely  deserve it :) I think Rachel won't mind :) So, now I really have to go, have been far too long in this office for today :) and btw, someone told me that this is not a chat ;)

Answer (score 0):

IF you use like

**Content="{Binding Path=Parameter Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}"**

then your problem might be solved...

Comment: ohh u didn't mention the **path** so i thought giving the proper code to guy can reduce his confusion.. ;)

Comment: what I meant was whether you have any suggestion left for me :) In the meantime I was able to locate the problem somewhere in the datagrid-binding-valueConverter scope :) Dont't you have any clue - i am really lost :)

Comment: this is the only thing which can help u Marc but dont knw why it is not working??? :(