# Notification of DataGrid when Collection inside Collection changes

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

Since hours I am working on a very hard problem:

How is a **DataGrid** that is bound to an **ObservableCollection** correctly **updated** when another ObservableCollection that is inside the **ObservableCollection** the **DataGrid** is bound to changes ?

So far the DataGrid onnly refreshes when i click on the corresponding cell.

I have prepared a complete source code example to illustrate the following (very simple) situation:

*There is a ViewModel that holds a List. This List is an ObservableCollection and hold two things: An integer and another List (again an ObservableCollection) that holds four integers.
Then there is a DataGrid that has two columns. One column for the integer number and one column for the list of integers.
This little application has buttons to modify the integers in the nested list i.e. adding +1 to one of the four integers.
The **GOAL** is that the modification of the nested list is getting reflected by the DataGrid.
The **PROBLEM** so far is, that this only happens on a with an external trigger (e.g. a click on the corresponding cell, or a click on one column header that sorts a column etc.)*

So here is the complete code:

**This is the ViewModel code that the DataGrid is bound to:**

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private Items items;

    public Items Items {
        get { return items; }
        set {
            items = value;
            firePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel() {

        Items = new Items();
    }

    private void firePropertyChanged(string property) {

        if (PropertyChanged != null) {


            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Items: ObservableCollection<Item> {

    public Items()
        : base() {

        this.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged);
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {


        if (e.NewItems != null) {

            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems) {

                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null) {

            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems) {

                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnCollectionChanged(a);
    }
}

public class List: ObservableCollection<NumberItem> {

    public List()
        : base() {

        this.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged);
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {

        if (e.NewItems != null) {

            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems) {

                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null) {

            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems) {

                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnCollectionChanged(a);
    }
}

public class NumberItem : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private int number;

    public int Number {
        get { return number; }
        set {
            number = value;
            firePropertyChanged("Number");   
        }
    }

    public NumberItem(int i) {

        Number = i;
    }

    private void firePropertyChanged(string property) {

        if (PropertyChanged != null) {

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private List list;

    public List List {
        get { return list; }
        set {
            list = value;
            firePropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

    private int numberOne;

    public int NumberOne {
        get { return numberOne; }
        set {
            numberOne = value;
            firePropertyChanged("NumberOne");
        }
    }

    private void firePropertyChanged(string property) {

        if (PropertyChanged != null) {

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

/// <summary>
/// This converter simply transforms the list of integers into a string.
/// </summary>
public class Converter : IValueConverter {

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

    List l = (List)value;

    string s = "";

    return s + l[0].Number + " " + l[1].Number + " " + l[2].Number + " " + l[3].Number;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

**The code of the buttons that manipulate the integers of the nested list is the following:**

```
private void plus1L(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        vm.Items[0].List[0].Number += 1;

    }
```

**And finally this is the XAML where the DataGrid is getting bound:**

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dg" Margin="17,139,21,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="164" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, HorizontalMargin">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="A" Header="A" Binding="{Binding NumberOne}"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="List" Header="List" Binding="{Binding List, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>*emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172990/546730) that you just need to fire change events for the `List` property when you change **anything** about it, it's not that hard...

**Edit:** In the handler you change the list **in some way** and you do nothing.

```
private void plus1L(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vm.Items[0].List[0].Number += 1;
    vm.Items[0].OnPropertyChanged("List"); // This is needed if you bind to List.
}
```

To be even more explicit about this: The binding does not care about anything other than the property path you bind to. Everything that happens inside the bound property is unknown to it, so you need to forward internal changes.

Comment: Yeah, you told me that. And I did what you were telling me ;) But it's still not working. Above is my complete source code - and if i understood you right a few hours before I have included that in the source code.

Comment: ok, it works now. I've simply lost the forest out of focus because of too many trees. And starring onto the same problem for hours is also not a good approach. Nevertheless if I had the possibility I would pay you a beer and/or drink it with you ... but here I just can say: Thank you! :)

Comment: ... but I assume I've annoyed you so much that you would drink your beer without me ;)

Comment: @Marc: You're welcome :) Don't worry about it, but you just could have clarified the problem in your other question as you did not give me the full picture, it would have saved both of us some trouble i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Why do people insist on creating classes which inherit from `ObservableCollection<SomeObject>`? Do they think something is wrong with using an `ObservableCollection<Item>` as a data type and using the **built-in** change notification???

Anyways, do this:

```
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> OuterCollection { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> InnerCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Your XAML can look like normal, however if you change a value in the `InnerCollection`, WPF does not know about it because an `ObservableCollection` is supposed to monitor the changes to a collection, not the changes to items in the collection.

To update the UI, you'll need to raise a `PropertyChange` notification for the `InnerCollection`.

```
myItem.InnerCollection[0]++;
myItem.RaisePropertyChanged("InnerCollection");
```

If the `InnerCollection` contains objects which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can subscribe to their `PropertyChanged` events to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `InnerCollection` when one of the items changes.

```
void SomeConstructor()
{
    InnerCollection = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>();
    InnerCollection.CollectionChanged += InnerCollection_CollectionChanged;
}

void InnerCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
        for each (SomeItem item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += SomeItem_PropertyChanged;

    if (e.OldItems!= null)
        for each (SomeItem item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= SomeItem_PropertyChanged;
}

void SomeItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("InnerCollection");
}
```

Comment: Hello Rachel :) nice to read you again :) H.B. companied me the whole day with my binding issue which we solved right now .. nevertheless Thank you also for giving me the right tip (myItem.RaisePropertyChanged("InnerCollection");) ... Regarding the ObservableCollection inheritance: I thought it is necessary to extend the collection with some abilities but to be honest i mainly do it to support a general programming style (i.e. if i want to extend i am able to) and because _ItemList items_ looks more appropriate than _ObservableCollection<int> items_ in the most cases :)

Comment: @Marc I suppose if you would extend `List<int>` into it's own class then I can see your reasoning, however if you wouldn't (and I would not!) then it doesn't need to be it's own class. The type name says it all: it's a observable collection, which is simply a collection with change notifications. Glad you got it sorted out though.

Comment: @Rachel and (@)H.B. You know what, i really like you guys :)

Comment: @Marc I'm not sure why... we both tend to get frustrated with SO questions and it shows in our answers / comments (HB more than me ^_^)